# Dreamweaver CS6 - restrict acces to a page

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I have an index.php page (which has user authentication implemented).
Successfull login takes you to download.php page.

On download.php I have set server behaviours-userauthentication-restrict access to page to redirect to index.php if access denied.But this is not working.I can still open the downloads pagedirectly by providing the link in the brower.

How can I prevent this?

Here is the code of the "downloads.php" :

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "1";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "Index.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
WTF page ...
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code of the index.php file which has login implemented:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/myconn.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_myconn, $myconn);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $myconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM users";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $myconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['Username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['Username'];
  $password=$_POST['Password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "ACC_LEVEL";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "downloads.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "Index.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_myconn, $myconn);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT `USER`, PASSWORD, ACC_LEVEL FROM users WHERE `USER`=%s AND PASSWORD=%s",
  GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $myconn) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {

    $loginStrGroup  = mysql_result($LoginRS,0,'ACC_LEVEL');

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryValidationTextField.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="LoginForm" id="LoginForm">
<h1><img src="logo.png" width="119" height="124" /></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="380" border="0,5" align="left">
    <tr>
      <td><div align="left"><span id="sprytextfield1">
      </span></div>        <span id="sprytextfield1">
        <label for="Username"></label>
        <div align="left">Username : <br />
          <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" />
          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></div>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="sprytextfield2">
      </span>        <span id="sprytextfield2">
        <label for="Password"></label>
        <div align="left">Password : <br />
          <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" />
          <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></div>
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="left">
        <input type="submit" name="LoginButton" id="LoginButton" value="Log in" />
      </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="left"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1");
var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield2");
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

Comment: where is the code that should prevent access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I forgot to do was to link the downloads.php page to my connection. Then it worked OK.